# How do I retrieve data from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I was on the "hospital_payment_data" table.
I want to call up the data of the number of data, the cache_account_received sum, and the total_medical_bills sum, and then bring up the mount sum value from the cash_recipit_rowtable to express. What should I do?

1. hospital_payment_data

   [image]
2. cash_receipt_row

   [image]

I want result

[image]

However, sending the following queries results in the following:

```sql
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as total,  
  SUM(cash_amount_received) AS sum_cash_amount_received, 
  COUNT(
    IF(total_medical_bills >= 100000 AND
    cash_amount_received , total_medical_bills, NULL)
  ) as obligatory_issue, 
  SUM(
    IF(total_medical_bills >= 100000 AND
    cash_amount_received , cash_amount_received, NULL)
  ) as sum_obligatory_issue, 
  SUM(amount) AS sum_amount 
FROM (
  SELECT total_medical_bills, cash_amount_received, amount 
  FROM hospital_payment_data, cash_receipt_row
) AS a
```

wrong result

[image]

Comment: You need to put `join` condition for 2 tables. `hospital_payment_data` and  `cash_receipt_row`. Your current SQL is doing a cross join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as total,  
  SUM(cash_amount_received) AS sum_cash_amount_received, 
  COUNT(
    IF(total_medical_bills >= 100000 AND
    cash_amount_received , total_medical_bills, NULL)
  ) as obligatory_issue, 
  SUM(
    IF(total_medical_bills >= 100000 AND
    cash_amount_received , cash_amount_received, NULL)
  ) as sum_obligatory_issue, 
  SUM(amount) AS sum_amount 
FROM (
  SELECT total_medical_bills, cash_amount_received, amount 
  FROM hospital_payment_data, cash_receipt_row 
WHERE hospital_payment_data.id = cash_receipt_row.id
) AS a
```

Comment: sql 1054 error 
id.cash_receipt_row in 'where clause' 
I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: I want to ask one more question.
What should I do with sum_oblitory_issue - sum_mount?

Comment: What is the issue?  COuld you please explain

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925394/i-want-to-do-sql-subtraction-what-should-i-do#comment107788796_60925394

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

You can also simplify your counting logic in MySQL.  There is no need for `IF()` or a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total,  
       SUM(cash_amount_received) AS sum_cash_amount_received, 
       SUM( total_medical_bills >= 100000 AND 
            obligatory_issue <> 0
          ) as obligatory_issue, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN total_medical_bills >= 100000
                THEN cash_amount_received
           END) as sum_obligatory_issue, 
       SUM(amount) AS sum_amount 
FROM hospital_payment_data hpd JOIN
     cash_receipt_row crr
     ON hpd.id = crr.id;
```

You'll notice that where conditional logic is needed, then this uses the standard SQL construct, `CASE`, rather than `IF`.